# Opening terminal asks for sudo password

Tags: 12.04, command-line, password, sudo

Whenever I open a new terminal within 12.04, I am prompted to enter my `sudo` password.

Why is this happening?

Comment: How are you opening your terminal(i.e. via icon)? You can try Alt+F2 and then type gnome-terminal, does it still ask for sudo?

Comment: Did you - by any chance - accidentally use the "Root Terminal" (purple icon) instead of the "Gnome Terminal" (black icon)?

Comment: the alt-f2 terminal does not appear on my screen. I was using the terminal which is found when simply typing in terminal into the unity interface. (black icon)

Comment: Have you customized `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Press Ctrl-Alt-F1, enter your username and password. You shouldn't be prompted for your password twice. Can you confirm? (Press Ctrl-Alt-F7 to get back to your graphical environment)

Comment: Please, open the terminal, enter your password and then type this command: `pstree -als $$`. That command has the answer to your question, so please paste the output here.

Answer (score 6):

Check your `.bashrc` file in your home directory. Sometimes it contains some `sudo` commands.

**More info:**

Open a terminal and press `Ctrl+C` when asked for the password. Then, to validate it's `.bashrc` causing the issue you can run

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Just make sure you did not previously ran any `sudo` commands so the password is not active.

If it asks for a password than something inside it or files included by it contain sudo commands.

I had this issue when I added an alias on my dev machine

```
alias clearphpsessions="cd /var/lib/php/sessions && sudo rm $(sudo ls /var/lib/php/sessions) && cd -"
```

Seems like the `$(sudo ls /var/lib/php/sessions)` part was interpreted, hence required the `sudo` password.